How to replace values in an array that is inside of a class?
I have ran into a problem where I have a class that stores an array, and also a method that is supposed to change the values in that array. The problem is when the code continues the values that the array gets are the default ones instead of the ones changed in the method.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace problemexample
{

    public class Stats
    {
        public int[] defStats = { 100, 15, 7 };

        public void ChangeStat(int stat1, int stat2, int stat3)
        {
            defStats[0] = stat1;
            defStats[1] = stat2;
            defStats[2] = stat3;
        }

    }
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Setup()
        {
            Stats player = new Stats();
            int[] stats = player.defStats;

            stats[0] = 150;
            stats[1] = 30;
            stats[2] = 10;

            player.ChangeStat(stats[0], stats[1], stats[2]);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Setup();
            Stats player = new Stats();
            int[] stats = player.defStats;

            foreach (int i in stats)
            {
                Console.Write(i + " ");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}


Please provide a [mcve] - what you've shown in the question is short, but incomplete. What's in the repo is far from minimal.

player.ChangeStat(statok[0], statok[1], statok[2]); Inside the function you are just assigning the same values to themselves. Maybe you are thinking that int[] statok = player.statok; creates a new array (copy)?

You can get a copy of an array with int[] statok = (int[])player.statok.Clone();

For what it's worth, arrays don't contain variables. Arrays of int contain values (arrays of reference type instances contain references). This may sound nit-picky, but if you get the terminology right, things make more sense conceptually. In your code, int[] statok is a variable, while player.statok is a field - that is referenced by your statok variable. The members of that array (there is only one, referenced by the variable in one case and by the field in the other) are simple integer values.

Why do you have your Setup method returning a reference of type System.Array and not int[]? Do you have a use case that justifies abstracting the type like that? Actual array types (like int[]) are easier to work with than Array

You don't show where you get new stat values to update the array.
It looks like currently your ChangeStat method is overwriting with the same values that statok already contains.
player.ChangeStat(statok[0], statok[1], statok[2]);
appears to be passing the original values back into your method.  I believe you want to replace statok[x] in this line with the variables for your new stat values.
